# Why Rails allows trailing characters in finder methods? (Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can able to find the record with all of the below methods, is there a way to avoid it?
I want to allow only numbers for the integer columns for all models.

```
    User.find(1) -> Works
    User.find("1")  -> Works
    User.find("1trailingstrings")  -> Works (i want this to be disabled)
    User.find(1) -> Works


    User.where(mynumber: "134")  -> Works
    User.where(mynumber: "134dsadsasd")  -> Works (i want this to be disabled)


    User.where(mynumber: [134])  -> Works
    User.where(mynumber: ["134"])  -> Works
    User.where(mynumber: ["134dsadsasd"])  -> Works (i want this to be disabled)
```

Comment: Please explain why/ your use case

Comment: These are not trailing strings [of characters]. These are trailing characters (in a string).

Answer (score 0):

---

> User.find("1trailingstrings")  -> Works (i want this to be disabled)

You can consider using a wrapper that delegates to [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) under the hood:

(this wrapper is not comprehensive, as @engineersmnky mentioned, [find](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) receives `*args`)

```rb
class UserWrapper
  def self.find(id)
    parsed_id = Integer(id, exception: false)

    return unless parsed_id
    # or raise an error

    User.find(parsed_id)
  end
end

UserWrapper.find(raw_id)
```

Or you can overwrite the `.find` method on `User`, e.g:

```rb
class User
  def self.find(id)
    parsed_id = Integer(id, exception: false)

    return unless parsed_id
    # or raise an error

    super(parsed_id)
  end
end

User.find(raw_id)
```

[Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) parses integers when a string contains only digits:

[image]

---

> Why Rails allows trailing strings in finder methods? (Rails 6)

If you are curious about why `to_i` was chosen, https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/ could be a better place to ask since it receives more attention from Rails contributors in general (personal observation, may be wrong).

[image]

---

Comment: Just a note: `find` accepts 1+ arguments as well as an `Array` e.g. `find(1)`, `find(1,2,3)` or `find([1,2,3])` are all acceptable usages

Comment: Nice observation, @engineersmnky. I will leave a note that my suggestion is not comprehensive.

Comment: it is same even for where conditions